# Url mod_rewrite for static chained pages

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

How can I achieve this with mod_rewrite?

```
from:
.com/index.php?menu=home
to:
.com/home
```

AND

```
from:
.com/index.php?menu=home&list=hello
to:
.com/home/hello
```

ALSO (without the folder hierarki)

```
from:
.com/index.php?menu=home&list=hello
to:
.com/hello
```

I'm using this for the first one:

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1 [L]
```

But how to I connect them if there are multiple variables?

Tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)?$ index.php?home=$1&list=$2
```

Comment: What do you mean by `multiple variables`? If you're talking about the GET variables, you need to set `[L,QSA]` which will pass all of the GET parameters to your script. For example, if the user goes to `.com/home/hello?testing=variable` it will pass it to the page. Is that what you're asking for ?

Comment: Updated my question. Last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood how the URL rewriting should be done. When you're using the `MVC` pattern, your URL tells the framework/bootstrapper which controller and method to execute. 
So, your URL should be looking something similar to: `http://host.com/CONTROLLER/ACTION/what/ever`. That's why you can't have `.com/index.php?menu=home&list=hello` re-written as `.com/hello`. There will be no way of differentiating when `http://host.com/hello` is a `controller` and when it's an `action`(method of the controller class).

The code below will rewrite:

1. `.com/whatever` as `.com/index.php?menu=whatever`
2. `.com/whatever/youwant` as `.com/index.php?menu=whatever&list=youwant`
3. `.com/whatever/youwant/with/additional/parameters` as `.com/index.php?menu=whatever&list=youwant&additional=$5`.

.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)([/])?([^/]*)?([/])?(.*)$ index.php?menu=$1&list=$3&additional=$5 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

A whole lot of headaches, why not create **1** rule and pass the route to your script and then use explode() to split and define:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in your PHP

```
<?php 
$route = explode('/',$_GET['route']);

$menu = (!empty($route[0])?:null);
$list = (!empty($route[1])?:null);
?>
```

BTW your 3rd example is impossible.